# Load Teradata table from excel using tpt loader

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have developed `python` and used `pandas module` to write `excel`.
While executing command *print(df1.columns)*, I get dtype as 'Object'.

and using same `excel` to load in `Teradata` table using `TPT script` and getting below error

*FILE_READER[1]: TPT19108 Data Format 'DELIMITED' requires all 'VARCHAR/JSON/JSON BY NAME/CLOB BY NAME/BLOB BY NAME/XML BY NAME/XML/CLOB' schema.*

Using Description in TPT:-

```
 DEFINE SCHEMA Teradata__DATA
 DESCRIPTION 'SCHEMA OF Teradata data'
 (
 Issue_Key VARCHAR(255),
 Log_Date VARDATE(10) FORMATIN ('YYYY-MM-DD') FORMATOUT ('YYYY-MM-DD'),
 User_Name VARCHAR(255),
 Time_Spent NUMBER(10,2)
```

Please help in resolving the failure message. Error might be due different Datatype or due to defined delimeter as "TAB". Please suggest if any other reason is causing this failure.

## CODE

```
df = pd.read_excel('Time_Log_Source_2019-05-30.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', dtype=str)
print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Issue Key', 'Log Date', 'User', 'Time Spent(Sec)'])
df['Log Date'] = df['Log Date'].str[:10]
df['Time Spent(Sec)'] = df['Time Spent(Sec)'].astype(int)/3600
print(df)
df.to_excel("Time_Log_Source_2019-05-30_output.xlsx")
df1 = pd.read_excel('Time_Log_Source_2019-05-30_output.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',dtype=str)
df1['Issue Key'] = df1['Issue Key'].astype('str')
df1['Log Date'] = df1['Log Date'].astype('str')
df1['User'] = df1['User'].astype('str')
df1['Time Spent(Sec)'] = df1['Time Spent(Sec)'].astype('str')
df1.to_excel("Time_Log_Source_2019-05-30_output.xlsx",startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False)
print(type(df1['Time Spent(Sec)']))
print(df.columns)
print(df1.columns)
```

*Result*

```
Index([u'Issue Key', u'Log Date', u'User', u'Time Spent(Sec)'], dtype='object')
Index([u'Issue Key', u'Log Date', u'User', u'Time Spent(Sec)'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The error clearly states the problem.  TPT wants all character type columns, you've got one defined as `number`.

Comment: My TD table is Time_Spent NUMBER(10,2), Can I change the description with varchar? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TPT Schema describes fields in client-side records, not columns in the database table. You would need to change the schema to say the (input) Time_Spent is VARCHAR.

But TPT does not natively read .xlsx files. Consider using `to_csv` instead of `to_excel`.

Comment: After changing to varchar, getting below error:FILE_READER[1]: TPT19134 !ERROR! Fatal data error processing file '/home/user/Time_Log_Source_2019-05-30_output.xlsx'. Delimited Data Parsing error: Column length overflow(s) in row 1.

Comment: Please suggest Fred or others

Comment: @HimanshuPant  I was overlooking the obvious larger issue. Corrected my response.

Comment: Thanks that helped